# Best way to handle and share data on Flex mobile

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air, adobe

I am just starting out with mobile development and the data handling for Flex mobile applications seem to be plain horror. I have spent two days on it, tried about 10 different approaches and still can't find a clen working solution.

So i have a TabbedViewNavigatorApplication with many views and subviews. All of them should be able to access the same data that i want to store in a model (so basically they need to access the same model class to add, edit and retrieve some data from there).

I create one instance of a model, pass it as data to all view stacks

If i change something in one view stack and switch to another one, i see the changes and all is fine.

But if I change the model data in one view and restart the application, I see changed data in that view but if i switch to another view, it has the old (unmodified) model. I would assume that the model would be the same instance but apparently each view has its own "model" when saving persistance data.

So how do you manage shared model over all views ? Ideally i would create it once on the first app launch, and then just add / remove items from any view or subview.

Or do i need to use the SQLite for that ? In this case it seems i would need to fetch the data for each view each time a view changes to stay up-to-date with the current data in the database ?

Please help :)

Comment: That depends on the complexity of your model, of course and is highly a matter of personal taste. Before somebody closes this as 'Not a real question', I recommend SQLite, just my personal taste ;)

Comment: So, what are those 10 different approaches you've already tried? Did you try bidirectional bindings? Did you try handling the proper change events of your model? Providing some code wouldn't hurt, too ...

Comment: Well, my actual problem is not the data handling itself but the fact that whenever i pass model to different view stacks, each one seem to store its own model (as data) and changes are not reflected in other view stacks. I have turned the persistNavigatorState to true and passing the same model to the viewstacks as firstViewData. If i change something in one view stack and then switch to another, i see the changes, that is not a problem. But if i chnage something in one, then restart the app and switch to another viewstack, it still has the "old" model

Comment: Sounds like you need to turn off persistNavigatorState and handle the load/save yourself. Whether to use SharedObjects or SQL depends on the complexity of your data.